# It is possible to get the data from Firebase Performance dashboard?

Tags: firebase, firebase-performance

Basically I cannot find any API for a node environment in order to extract the data from Firebase Performance.

The outcome would be extracting that data in order to integrate it with a Grafana panel.

The official docs from Firebase are not helping.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there's no available API to download or get data directly from the Firebase Performance dashboard. You may [link your Firebase project to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765) and [export performance data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/bigquery-export) (traces, metrics, network requests, etc.) for each of your apps.

From here, you can [use BigQuery as a data source for Grafana](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-bigquery-datasource/).